# Como iniciar o Select baseado em valor de um Model do escopo AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, bind

Tenho o seguinte código (com a listagem funcionando OK):

```
<select 
ng-model="elementoAtivo.tipo" 
ng-init="elementoAtivo.tipo = elementoAtivo.tipo" 
ng-options="a.valor as a.opcao for a in [{'valor':0,'opcao':'SIMPLES'},{'valor':1,'opcao':'COMPLEXO'},{'valor':2,'opcao':'TESTE'}]">
</select>
```

Quero inicializar o Option com um valor que *já vem* no model **elementoAtivo.tipo** que é um inteiro entre 0 e 3), porem ele inicia o dropdown vazio e quando clico mostra as outras opções.

Como faço para checar se o valor de **elementoAtivo.tipo** é o mesmo de uma das opções que coloquei no ng-options e com isso ja inicializar com ela marcada?

Answer (score 0):

Você esta percorrendo uma lista de `object` e seu `ng-model` recebe um inteiro, ou seja não dá "match" para que o `select` saiba o que deve ser exibido. Por isso o valor preenchido na variável **elementoAtivo.tipo** não reflete no select.

Para fazer referência a um objeto pelo seu identificador é necessário adicionar a cláusula `track by` que informará qual atributo do objeto será preenchido pelo `ng-model` e que deverá ser usado para localizar o objeto na lista e então o exibir no `<select>`.

Assim sendo, basta adicionar `track by a.valor` no fim do atributo `ng-options`. Seu código ficará (mais ou menos) assim:

```
<select 
ng-model="elementoAtivo.tipo" 
ng-init="elementoAtivo.tipo = elementoAtivo.tipo" 
ng-options="a.valor as a.opcao for a in [{'valor':0,'opcao':'SIMPLES'},{'valor':1,'opcao':'COMPLEXO'},{'valor':2,'opcao':'TESTE'}] track by a.valor">
</select>
```

Obs:

1. Documentação para `ng-options`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions
2. Espero que ainda seja útil ;)